# Last row not showing properly in GridView

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview, browser

[image]

Hi,

This issue is only reflecting in Google Chrome,

In style

```
.GridviewScrollHeader > TH, .GridviewScrollHeader > TD {
padding: 5px; white-space: normal;
border-right: 1px solid #a5bed4; 
border-left: 1px solid #fff; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
border-top:none; 
background:url(../Images/grid_head.jpg) repeat-x top center #cfe4ff;
text-align: left; 
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the height to the grid then this problem can be solved. For example:

```
height: 250,
autowidth: true
width: 1100,
```